# MATLAB: find intersection points with "solve" [circle + linear equation]

Tags: matlab

I would like to find the two (2) intersection points when a linear line goes through a circle's centrum (x,y).

```
r  =  13   radius
x  =  0    x-coordinate
y  =  7    y-coordinate
k  =  9    slope value(?) y=kx+m y=9x+m
```

So first I'm drawing a circle with r=13 and a centrum of (0,7).

```
r=13
x=0
y=7
k=9

hold on
z = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
xunit = r * cos(z) + x;
yunit = r * sin(z) + y;
plot(xunit, yunit);
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to plot up a circle in an easier way? Something like

```
(x−cx)^2 + (y −cy)^2 = r^2
(x-0)^2 + (y-7) = 13^2
```

I've tried this

```
plot((x−cx)^2 + (y −cy)^2 = r^2)
```

It doesn't do anything at all so the code must be incorrect.

Well, then I'm drawing the linear equation by calculating

```
y=kx+m
k=9
```

the line goes thorugh (0,7)

```
7=9*0+m
m=7
y=9x+7
```

so since I'm new to MatLab it took me a while to actually draw the line. I didn't find any easy function to plot it so I plotted a line like this:

I took some random values for x or y and calculated some coordinates.

```
(0,7) 
(2,25)
(-2,-11)

plot([-2,2],[-11,25])
```

Result image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ2xe.jpg

So now I just need to solve the intersection points with "solve" function. So well I would really appreciate some help!

best regards

Comment: Why use solve? Why not just solve it analytically?

Comment: Is the mapping toolbox available to you? If yes, use linecirc()

Comment: Dan it's a school task I "must" use solve function...

lhcgeneva could you explain a little more in detail? What should I do with linecirc() so I can solve it with solve()?

[xout,yout] = linecirc(9,intercpt,0,7,13)

Comment: and yes I've Mapping toolbox!

Comment: Read this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-algebraic-equations.html and the docs for `solve`

Comment: I can't manage to solve this problem and it makes me insane. I solved it using GeoGebra within 2 minutes but I've been sitting with MatLab for a whole day and I'm still stuck and I don't even know if anything what I've done is "correct".. I'll have to ask the teacher because I can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to it:

```
%Place your lines and figures on the grid
linexypos = eye(100);
shapexypos = flipud(eye(100)) ;

% Guess where they come together
intersection = filter2(ones(3),linexypos + shapexypos);
[quality, loc] = max(intersection(:))
```

Note that you have to guess, as two lines with widths of 1 pixel may not have exactly the same location. (consider `[1 0; 0 1]` and `[0 1;1 0]`, they cross but never exactly overlap).

If you want to visualize the situation, try `contour(intersection)`